# How can I pass style info to a grid?

Tags: angular

I have an `ag-grid` component which takes a a style in the HTML file which looks like this:

```
style="height: 600px; width: 100%"
```

Using it like this works fine but I am trying to set the height and width from outside and there is where I am having issues. If for example I use

```
style="height: {{gridHeight}}; width: {{gridWidth}}"
```

It does not work. I am not sure what I am missing here. Also, is there a way to check if there is a value for `{{gridHeight}}` then we use it otherwise we use lets say `500px`?

This is how i setup the grid in my html template so div stuff is not an option..

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isInfiniteScrollGrid; else paginatedGrid">
    <ag-grid-angular #gridInstance style="height: 600px; width: 100%"
        class="{{theme}}"
        [columnDefs]="gridColumnDefs"
        [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
        [enableRangeSelection]="enableRangeSelection"
        [rowDeselection]="rowDeselection"
        [sideBar]="sideBar"
        [rowModelType]="rowModelType"
        [cacheBlockSize]="cacheBlockSizeInfiniteScroll"
        [maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests]="maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests"
        [infiniteInitialRowCount]="infiniteInitialRowCount"
        [getRowNodeId]="getRowNodeId"
        [rowData]="rowData"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
        [isExternalFilterPresent]="isExternalFilterPresent"
        [doesExternalFilterPass]="doesExternalFilterPass"
        [suppressRowClickSelection]="suppressRowClickSelection"
        (modelUpdated)="onModelUpdated()"
        (columnVisible)="toggleColumnVisibility($event)"
        (gridReady)="onReady($event)"
        (columnMoved)="onColumnEvent($event)"
        (columnResized)="onColumnEvent($event)">
    </ag-grid-angular>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `height` and `width` variable in your TypeScript file and then use a if statement within `[ngStyle]`.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{
  'height':this.height === 800 ? '800px' : '500px',
  'width':this.width === 800 ? '800px' : '500px'
}"></div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hello-world-bsna6f?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: i can not use the div since i need to declare the style in my component. I provided an sample on how my component is setup

Answer (score -1):

You can pass collection of style as key-value pair , check this [Angular Document](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)
In your case the `style` object in component would be:

```
readonly styles = {
height: '600px',
width: '100%'
};
```

and template should be

```
<div [ngStyle]="styles"></div>
```

Comment: that is not my issue , why component expects the style to be defined like this style="height: 600px; width: 100%" the question i have is how can i get the height dynamicly in the html file

Comment: Did you tried passing ``ngStyle`` to ``ag-grid-angular`` as a set of styles object ?